# Python Celery Received unregistered task of type - import app error

Tags: python, import, celery

I can't import my celery app to run tasks from my main Python application. I want to be able to run celery tasks from the myprogram.py file.

My celery_app.py file is as follows:

```
import celery

app = celery.Celery('MyApp', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

app.conf.broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.conf.result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(ignore_result=True)       
def task_to_run():
    print("Task Running")

# The following call runs a worker in celery
task_to_run.delay()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Application structure

- projectfolder/core/celery_app.py # Celery app
- projectfolder/core/myprogram.py  # My Python application
- projectfolder/core/other python files...

The file myprogram.py contains the following:

```
from .celery_app import task_to_run
task_to_run.delay()
```

Error:

```
Received unregistered task of type 'projectfolder.core.celery_app.task_to_run'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'projectfolder.core.celery_app.task_to_run'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

interesting, I didn't know about `autodiscover_tasks`, I guess it's new in 4.1

As I see in the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.autodiscover_tasks), this function takes list of packages to search. You might want to call it with:

`app.autodiscover_tasks(['core.celery_app'])`

or it might be better to extract the task to a seperate file called `tasks.py` and then it would be just: 
`app.autodiscover_tasks(['core'])`.

Alternatively, you can use the `inculde` parameter when creating the `Celery` instance:

`app = celery.Celery('MyApp', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', include=['core.celery_app'])` or wherever your tasks are.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In case of you have deleted tasks and it's appeared as `unregistred task`  , you have to flush the Redis cache:

```
redis-cli FLUSHDB
```